# Getting text from a dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I'm trying to get a value from a pop-up that my program creates. It goes like this:

```
private void btnCheckoutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


    do
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price","");
        itemPrice = Double.parseDouble() 

    while();
```

So how do I get text from the input dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private void btnCheckoutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

do
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price","");
    itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(value) 

while();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since JOptionPane.showInputDialog.. returns a String all you need to do is declare it as a String like this

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price","");
```

Answer (score 3):

`showInputDialog` returns a String for text entries or Object for combo box selections. See ["How to Make Dialogs#Getting the User's Input from a Dialog"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input).

```
boolean valid = false;
do {
    try {
        itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item price"));
        valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
} while(!valid);
```